# Getting Network Link conditioner to only affect iOS Simulator, not the entire Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos

Is there a way to use Apple's Network Link Conditioner in such a way that it only affects the iOS Simulator, and not the rest of the Mac?

My KB+M is connected to the Mac via a program called Synergy, which lets me share my Windows KB+M with it, and attempting to run unit tests on the iOS Simulator with any packet loss profiles selected in the Network Link Conditioner makes it almost impossible to control the Mac at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue for a while and have been trying to find a solution.

I eventually gave up and started using the Charles Web Proxy instead because it's free (they claim only for 30 days but it works forever) and it allows you to choose which websites you want to throttle internet access for.

Please share if you can do something like that with the network link conditioner.